# How to resolve these errors during upgrade ruby?

Tags: ruby, osx-lion, upgrade

```
Fetching yaml-0.1.4.tar.gz to /Users/dmonkeys/.rvm/archives
Extracting yaml-0.1.4.tar.gz to /Users/dmonkeys/.rvm/src
Error running 'tar xmzf /Users/dmonkeys/.rvm/archives/yaml-0.1.4.tar.gz -C /Users/dmonkeys/.rvm/src ', please read /Users/dmonkeys/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p194/yaml/extract.log
Configuring yaml in /Users/dmonkeys/.rvm/src/yaml-0.1.4.
Error running ' ./configure --prefix="/Users/dmonkeys/.rvm/usr"  ', please read     /Users/dmonkeys/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p194/yaml/configure.log
Compiling yaml in /Users/dmonkeys/.rvm/src/yaml-0.1.4.
Error running 'make  -j2', please read /Users/dmonkeys/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p194/yaml/make.log

Database file /Users/dmonkeys/.rvm/config/packages does not exist.

Installing Ruby from source to: /Users/dmonkeys/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...

ruby-1.9.3-p194 - #fetching 
ruby-1.9.3-p194 - #extracted to /Users/dmonkeys/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p194 (already extracted)
ruby-1.9.3-p194 - #configuring 
Error running ' ./configure --prefix=/Users/dmonkeys/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194 --enable-shared --disable-install-doc --with-libyaml --with-opt-dir=/Users/dmonkeys/.rvm/usr ', please read /Users/dmonkeys/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p194/configure.log
There has been an error while running configure. Halting the installation.
ruby-1.9.3-p194 is not installed.
Creating alias default for ruby-1.9.3-p194.
Recording alias default for ruby-1.9.3-p194.
Creating default links/files
ruby-1.9.3-p194 is not installed.
Could not load ruby ruby-1.9.3-p194.
/Users/dmonkeys/.rvm/scripts/alias: line 133: /Users/dmonkeys/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby: No such file or directory
```

Comment: It'd be nice if you were more specific about your platform in the question rather than leaving it as something to be discerned from the tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have the Xcode "Command Line Tools" package installed. Xcode alone is no longer sufficient.

You can do this by downloading them separately or by enabling that package in the Organizer.

This is the most common case for installation failure. You didn't post the contents of the log that was mentioned in the output you pasted.